# how to find all links inside nested lists using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<ul class="main">
<li> 
<a href="/1.html"></a>
</li>
<a href="/2.html"></a>
<li>
<a href="/3.html"></a>
</li>

</ul>

<ul class="main2">
<li> 
<a href="/1.mp4"></a>
</li>
<a href="/2.mp4"></a>
<li>
<a href="/3.mp4"></a>
</li>

</ul>
```

as i can't use soup.findAll("ul",class_="main").ul.a["href=True"]

i want output like from main class

`["/1.html","/2.html","/3.html"]`

Comment: What have you tried (in code) so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `.main a` -> this will find all `<a>` tags under tag with `class="main"`:

```
print([a['href'] for a in soup.select('.main a')])
```

Prints:

```
['/1.html', '/2.html', '/3.html']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to evaluate a result on each step when you construct a complex expression.

Use method `find` when you want a single element. Use `find_all` when you want an array (list) of elements. When your expression returns an array just iterate it!

```
[e['href'] for e in soup.find('ul',{'class':'main'}).find_all('a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = []
for x in (soup_1.find_all('ul', class_ = "main" )):
    a = x.findChildren("a")
    for href in a:
        list1.append(href['href'])

print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

html = """
<ul class="main">
<li> 
<a href="/1.html"></a>
</li>
<a href="/2.html"></a>
<li>
<a href="/3.html"></a>
</li>

</ul>

<ul class="main2">
<li> 
<a href="/1.mp4"></a>
</li>
<a href="/2.mp4"></a>
<li>
<a href="/3.mp4"></a>
</li>

</ul>
"""
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
print (doc.selects('ul.main>a>href()'))
# Or
print (doc.select('ul.main').selects('a>href()'))
```

Result:

```
['/1.html', '/2.html', '/3.html']
```